# Is there a tag for "single user mode"?

Tags: support, tags

Just created a tag for a question that was specifically about single user mode, and searched for a tag about it, but didn't see one. Just want to correct my mistake if it already exists.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with that gets close would be [tag:runlevel].

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @Braiam it was in response to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/533378/black-screen-in-single-user-mode